# Getting extra 'li' in ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Every time user click on li, new ul should be added to that li, basically want to create binary tree using ul

```js
$('#tree').on('click','li', function(){

  $(this).append('<ul style="display:block;"><li>list1</li><li>list2</li></ul>'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tree">
     <li>
    sdfsdf 
   </li>
  </ul>
```

list is getting added twice when list1 is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stop the propagation of the click event, i.e.

```
$('#tree').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).append('<ul style="display:block;"><li>list1</li><li>list2</li></ul>');     
});
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/63955/)

Comment: downvoters, please explain the reason.. the solution solves OP's issue

Comment: is there way to limit it to add ul only once? like each li should have only one ul. In above code i am able to add multiple ul to li

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `event.stopPropagation();` so that the parent event is not propagated. Since, click on `li` inside a `li` will trigger click event twice, you need to stop the click event of the parent and only trigger the one which you have clicked.

```js
$('#tree').on('click','li', function(event){
 event.stopPropagation();
  var ulExist = $(this).find('ul');
  if(ulExist.length === 0){
    $(this).append('<ul style="display:block;"><li>list1</li><li>list2</li></ul>'); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tree">
  <li>
      sdfsdf  
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: People are really amazing here. Can someone explain why it was down voted? @AbdulHameed

Comment: is there way to limit it to add ul only once? like each li should have only one ul. In above code i am able to add multiple ul to li

Comment: @shefali what do you mean? ul>li>ul only? and not ul>li>ul>li>ul>li...?

Comment: click on list1 more than once , it is adding ul more than once. I want to limit it and allow only one ul per li. Which means if i click on list1 more than once it should not add more than one ul to clicked li

Comment: @shefali you have accepted and tick marked another answer. Was this answer not helpful? I have also updated it as you need.

Comment: I did upvote your answer and both answers are correct, it is just i cannot mark correct on more than one answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168413/discussion-between-ankit-agarwal-and-shefali).